# how to call again same APIs when response is other then status code 200 or error (some time)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i am using APIs call in my iPhone (objective C) app. my APIS call returns Status code 200, but some time it does return 405 response. when i restart my app i do get proper response.
how to call back same API when i get other then 200 response or if i get error...so that i don't have to restart app again.

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

             NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",
            [arrTokenData valueForKey:@"Token"]];

            //Configure session with common header fields
            NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        sessionConfiguration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{@"Authorization": authValue};

            NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];

            NSString *url = @"http://test.myserver.am/api/mobile/LookUps/getuserdata";
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

            NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
                if (!error) {
                    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
                    if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200)
                    {
                        //Process the data
                    }
                    else if
                    {
                     // how to call back same API
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // how to call back same API
                }

            }];
            [task resume];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: use recursive function concept.

Comment: You should deal with your 405 method not allowed error.

Comment: call same method again when you get error, that will solve your problem

Comment: no some time i get ..it is not always... i could not make how to deal from within call itself.....// how to call back same API in this block?

Comment: put this code in method like callAPI and re call it when ever you want

Answer (score 0):

I considered as you created a generic method of network call. If you will get an error or other than 200 response. Just take the request details from your request and call that generic method with that request(URL).

**Sample code:**

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *DataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:theRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
    NSHTTPURLResponse *serverResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    if (error == nil) {
        if (serverResponse.statusCode == 200) {
            NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:
                                [data bytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"%@", theXML);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@, %@", serverResponse.URL, serverResponse.allHTTPHeaderFields);
            //Call the generic network call method with the above details again
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", error. localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"%@, %@", serverResponse.URL, serverResponse.allHTTPHeaderFields);
        //Call the generic network call method with the above details again
    }


}];
[DataTask resume];
```

Create new thread and execute the failed requests.

Comment: no i have not created any generic method.  if i create generic method, response i have to save in different array's which would be difficult to keep track which APIs call response it is.  can i call same method again like for 1 min. max 1 min it can call itself if still response is same i can communicate response to user....like "server not responding at the movement , try after some time " something..but i do not have any proper example.... since i am using APIs first time..

Answer (score -1):

Create one method and write your code in that method and call same method on error like below

```
- (void)callService {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

    NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",
                           [arrTokenData valueForKey:@"Token"]];

    //Configure session with common header fields
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    sessionConfiguration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{@"Authorization": authValue};

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];

    NSString *url = @"http://test.myserver.am/api/mobile/LookUps/getuserdata";
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
        if (!error) {
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
            if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200)
            {
                //Process the data
            }
            else
            {
                // how to call back same API
                [self callService];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // how to call back same API
            [self callService];
        }

    }];
    [task resume];
}
```